# Postfix virtual domain mapping for a Linux username containing @

Tags: email, postfix, configuration, unix

I could not make Postfix work with Linux usernames containing @

Postfix has virtual domain map, in `/etc/postfix/virtual`

It looks something like this:

```
domain.ru                       domain.ru
administrator@domain.ru         me@example.ru
moderator@domain.ru             me@example.ru
```

It means that all mail going to users `administrator@domain.ru` and `moderator@domain.ru` must be delivered to the Linux user with name `me@example.ru`

However, when I use no `@` in Linux username, like `me.example.ru`, things work regular way.

I found out that `saslauth` rejected to work with `me@example.ru` unless it's load with `-r` flag. Is there something familiar should be done to Postfix, to make it work the same way?

I also tried `me\@example.ru`, escaping it. No effect. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you want to treat/deliver messages to **OTHER** addresses in example.ru?

Comment: They have the same structure as the example above but just for `example.ru`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to hints from postfix-users@postfix.org you should use `virtual` mailer instead of `local` mailer for deliveries to `me@example.ru`.

As I understand you may:
1. Put `example.ru` domain in virtual_mailbox_domains list
2. Use virtual mailbox map (vmailbox) to specify location of me@example.ru mailbox-file/maildir
3. Use virtual uid map to set owner of `me@example.ru` mailbox file(s)
[it selects OS account/user (numerical) identifier]

http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_mailbox

---

[[postfix-users] OS accounts/users with @](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.postfix.users/7oQM2dcKk-A)

> To: postfix-users at postfix org
>   Subject: Re: OS accounts/users with @
>   Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 11:21:12 -0400 (EDT)
>   Message-Id: <3mhwS83SMSzJrQ1@spike.porcupine.org>
>   From: wietse@porcupine.org (Wietse Venema)
>   [...]
>   In any case, using UNIX system account names with @ is a mistake,
>   and I will not put in a great deal of effort to make that easy.
>
> Wietse

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks for extra, interesting investigation on Google Groups

Answer (score 2):

What directive used in `main.cf` for that `/etc/postfix/virtual` ?
There're a bunch of `maps`.

I would use for such things in `main.cf` just

```
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/usr/local/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/usr/local/etc/postfix/sender_bcc
```

where you can manipulate with copies of sent/received emails.

Syntax of `recipient_bcc/sender_bcc` is pretty simple (as all in `postfix`)

```
# Email to catch                       email to send copy
administartor@domain.ru                realAdmin@SomeDomain.ru
moderator@domain.ru                    realAdmin@SomeDomain.ru
```

Advantage of using `bcc` - You can assign some admin and monitor him or keep related to `administartor@domain.ru` emails in his account and keep clean `realAdmin@SomeDomain.ru` account, when you get msg you can safely delete it since you know you always have a copy in real account. If assigned admin delete some msg, you anyway will have a copy as evidence if he/she something wrong.

Comment: There is no directives should be in `main.cf` about virtual domains. I'm not sure how your answer will help me to solve my problem. The problem is, that Postifix needs additional settings (if there are any in this concern) to make it work.

Comment: `recipient_bcc_maps` is not related to virtual domains only, it catching  every emails passed through the server. This directive used in `main.cf` as a global parameters and just point to external file shown above. If you won't such solution as `bcc` check, then you need to use `virtual_alias_maps`

Comment: BTW, **"There is no directives should be in main.cf about virtual domains."** - If `main.cf` will not have directive about virtual domains, then how did you point to `/etc/postfix/virtual` ?

Comment: The problem is that `realAdmin@SomeDomain.ru` is local Linux username and it falls into loop.

Comment: Check  this: http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html how to deal with that.

Comment: I have looked through it before. Not sure where the right answer is. If you know, please be more specific.

Comment: Create system alias in `/etc/aliases` as `localLinuxUser:           SomeUser@realEmailDomain.tld` and create aliases from other emails to `SomeUser@realEmailDomain.tld` in the `postfix` or use `bcc` to `SomeUser@realEmailDomain.tld` after that. P.S. - Do not forget to run `newaliases` if you changed `/etc/aliases`

Comment: My `localLinuxUser` is an email address, that Postfix has in postfix/virtual file. Does it change anything from your point of view?

Comment: Is this possible to use Linux UID in `/etc/postfix/virtual`?

Comment: You said `realAdmin@SomeDomain.ru is local Linux username` that means it is OS's system user. It won't appear automatically (even trough UID) in `virtual` unless you told to `postfix` via `/etc/aliases`. "Virtual" maps isn't related to system user from the view of `postfix`.

Comment: ..but if I set alias1 in `virtual`, and I set alias1: me@example.com in `aliases` then it falls into loop?

Comment: Alex, my question was about how to make things work differently, when they already work find the way they are. In case, in `virtual` I set destination user as `me.example.ru` - it's _all fine_ then BUT if I use `me@example.ru`, then Postfix says **unknown user**!? What should I do?